# array always returns null how to stop this

Tags: php, arrays

I have a php script that uses curl to get the contents of a json feed. Everything works fine until i try to return the "q" values in the json feed. The code below only returns "null".  How can I fix this? I suspect it has to do with the line `$search_term = $term[$number]->q;` but I am not 100% sure.

```
$lmgtfy_json_feed = get_data('http://live.com/');
$lmgtfy_search_term = json_decode($lmgtfy_json_feed);
$number = rand(0, count($lmgtfy_search_term)-1);
$search_term = $lmgtfy_search_term[number]->q;

echo json_encode($search_term);
```

Comment: what does `var_dump($term[$number])` say? if NULL, what does `var_dump($term)` say (should be pretty long, just parse the first few lines to get the idea)

Comment: @Stefan N `var_dump($term[$number])` sometimes will show the "q" string and other times it shows the string "null" more often it just shows "null"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using your complete array `$number` as key for `$term`.

If you want to pick a random element from the array `$term`, use PHP's [`rand`](http://php.net/rand) function instead of creating and shuffling an array:

```
$number = rand(0, count($term)-1);
$search_term = $term[$number]->q;
```

Comment: it works but if i refresh the page a couple times it starts to show "null" again?

Comment: Does the array `$term` always contain 500 items? I updated my answer to take a variable array length into account. I also included `0` in the rand function, since the previous code would never return the first item of the `$term` array.

Comment: just use array_rand as described in my answer and you'll be fine as it uses the actual arrays and therefore always finds a key from that array.

Comment: Since the array is decoded from JSON it will only contain numeric indices.

Comment: @jeff: Please show us the first few lines of output from `var_dump`

Comment: @knittl I added my full code, and now var_dump is showing null and so it the curl output

Comment: when `get_data(...)` returns `NULL`, what does `var_dump(curl_error($curl))` (before `curl_close()` say) ?

Comment: ok i fixed the curl and put up the results for `var_dump($lmgtfy_search_term)`

Comment: @jeff: I don't see a reason why my (or StefanN's code for that matter) should not work with the array output you provided.

Comment: @knittl ok its working now. i had to restart the ftp. if i can ask one more thing? right now it returns the 1st "q" in the array how would i change it so that it returns a random "q" in the array and not the 1st each time

Comment: @jeff: `$number` contains a random index in the range of 0 through the number of elements in the array (inclusive), so it should definitely return a random element from the array. Can you try to output `$number` before using it?

Comment: @knittl used a wrong variable haha ok great everything is in tip top shape :) thanks, and thank you too Stefan N

Answer (score 1):

simply use

```
$term_item = $term[array_rand($term, 1)];
$search_term = (string)$term_item->q;
```

hope that helps.

Comment: `array_rand` will return an array of keys, so you still need to get the first item.

Comment: nope this is a false statement, @knittl ! `array_rand($arr,1)` returns the key, because second argument is 1. see documentation: http://de3.php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php

Comment: Sorry, I overread that part of the documentation. Nevermind, you still got your +1 ;)